# Microsoft Graph API query failing with provided filter

Tags: .net, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

In my .NET application, I'm trying to get users from Azure AD B2C using Microsoft Graph API. I also want to filter these users based on a custom user attribute.

I've built this URL

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=extension_{Id}_lastUpdatedDate&$filter=extension_{Id}_lastUpdatedDate eq '2019-08-10'
```

This returns 400 error saying that `extension_{Id}_lastUpdatedDate` does not exist

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
    "message": "Property 'extension_{Id}_lastUpdatedDate' does not exist as a declared property or extension property.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "a925b2f4-fef8-47a1-b644-9b2e652f1746",
      "date": "2019-09-13T14:14:00"
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I sent exactly the same request, just except the filter part of the query, like this

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=extension_{Id}_lastUpdatedDate
```

I receive 200 with the results, which sounds like the field exists and is correctly filled for all users in AD

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(extension_{Id}_lastUpdatedDate)",
    "value": [
        {"extension_{Id}_lastUpdatedDate": "2018-07-12T14:31:47.208Z"}, 
        {"extension_{Id}_lastUpdatedDate": "2018-05-30T14:28:47.208Z"}, 
        {"extension_{Id}_lastUpdatedDate": "2018-06-30T14:28:47.208Z"}, 
        {"extension_{Id}_lastUpdatedDate": "2018-07-30T14:28:47.208Z"}, 
        {"extension_{Id}_lastUpdatedDate": "2018-08-30T14:28:47.208Z"}, 
        {"extension_{Id}_lastUpdatedDate": "2018-07-12T14:31:47.208Z"}, 
        {"extension_{Id}_lastUpdatedDate": "2018-07-30T14:31:47.208Z"}, 
        {"extension_{Id}_lastUpdatedDate": "2018-07-30T14:31:47.208Z"}
    ]
}
```

Does anyone know what's going on here? What the error message says sounds almost impossible to me, if I see the fields in a select query.

Comment: Support for newer Microsoft Graph API for querying Azure AD B2C tenant is still under development. I don't think we can get the same result through Microsoft Graph API. I also test it in Microsoft Graph explorer. But I get empty result for ```https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=extension_{Id}_{custom attribute}```. How did you create the custom attribute?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. The API is case sensitive in the $filter function, but not in the $select function. So make sure your $filter has a case sensitive correct name.

This doesn't work:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=extension_{id}_tenantId,displayName&$filter=extension_{id}_tenantId eq 1
```

This works:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=extension_{id}_tenantId,displayName&$filter=extension_{id}_TenantId eq 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same in my tenant and it works. The extension property shoesize in my case is a string. Could you please confirm the type of your extension property? And try with an extension property which has type = string?

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=extension_d09380e2b4c642b9a203fb816a04a7ad_ShoeSize&$filter=extension_d09380e2b4c642b9a203fb816a04a7ad_ShoeSize eq '12'
```

You can also try AADGraph (https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net)

```
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users?$select=extension_d09380e2b4c642b9a203fb816a04a7ad_ShoeSize&$filter=extension_d09380e2b4c642b9a203fb816a04a7ad_ShoeSize eq 'abhi'
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you still need to use the legacy Azure AD Graph API with AAD B2C. From the [B2C documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet):

> You must use the [Azure AD Graph API](/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-operations-overview) to manage users in an Azure AD B2C directory. This is different from the Microsoft Graph API. Learn more [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2016/07/08/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/).

While there are a number of scenarios where you can get away with using Microsoft Graph against AAD B2C, you'll more often or not get tripped up by something like this. Unless there is functionality you specifically need from Microsoft Graph, I would avoid using it until it is officially supported.